# changing the background opacity of a Bootstrap 3 navbar with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the opacity of an element as I scroll down a page, however my element background color will not change

```
$(document).on('scroll', function (e) {
    $('.navbar-default').css('background-color: rgba',"70","103","26",($(document).scrollTop() / 550));
});
```

my css

```
.navbar-default {
   /* background-color: #1b1d2a;  */
    background-color: rgba(70,103,26,0.1);
    border-color: #1b1d2a;
}
```

my problem seems to be not understanding the [jQuery .css() API docs](https://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties) on how to manipulate this particular style `background-color: rgba(70,103,26,0.1);` as I have seen this method work in other examples.

**[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/menriquez/L235efdv/)**

Comment: So exactly what results do you expect and get?

Comment: i expected a smooth transition from transparent to opaque but instead got no change at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(document).on('scroll', function (e) {

     var alpha = $(document).scrollTop() / 550;

     $('.navbar-default').css('background-color', 'rgba(70, 103, 26,' + alpha + ')');
});
```

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/L235efdv/2/)